# Can't see cv2 window on tkinter fullscreen

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, window

My code is working perfectly, but when I use it in tkinter fullscreen and then call `cv2.imshow("Image", img_, )`, the image opens in the backside of main tkinter window. My question is :**How can I bring my cv2 image in front of the tkinter window which is in fullscreen.**

My code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import cv2

def h():
    gui_cv = Tk()
    img_ = ''
    cartoon = ''
    def browse():
        g = fd.askopenfilename(parent=gui_cv)
        address_img.set(g)

    def real_img():
        global img_
        img_ = cv2.resize(img_, (700, 500))
        cv2.imshow("Image", img_, )

    def save_as():
        f = fd.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                                     ("PNG", "*.py"), ("jpg", "*.jpg")], parent=gui_cv)
        print(f)
        cv2.imwrite(f, cartoon)

    def cartoonized_img():
        global cartoon
        cartoon = cv2.resize(cartoon, (700, 500))
        cv2.imshow("Cartoon", cartoon)

    def cartoonize():
        global cartoon, img_
        button.pack_forget()
        button_1.pack_forget()

        img_ = cv2.imread(address_img.get())

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
        edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)

        color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_, 9, 250, 250)
        cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=edges)

        button_2 = Button(gui_cv, text='Real_Img', command=real_img, bd=4, bg='dodger blue2',
                          font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
        button_2.pack()
        button_3 = Button(gui_cv, text='Cartoonized_Img', bd=4, command=cartoonized_img, bg='dodger blue2',
                          font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
        button_3.pack(pady=10)
        button_4 = Button(gui_cv, text='Save As', bd=4, command=save_as, bg='dodger blue2',
                          font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
        button_4.pack()
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    def l(d):
        gui_cv.destroy()
    gui_cv.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
    gui_cv.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    gui_cv.bind('<ButtonPress-3>', l)
    gui_cv.title('Cartoonizer')
    gui_cv.resizable(0, 0)
    address_img = StringVar()
    entry_img = Entry(gui_cv, bd=6, textvariable=address_img, width=40, font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
    entry_img.pack(ipady=5)
    button = Button(gui_cv, text='Browse', command=browse, bd=4, bg='dodger blue2', font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
    button.pack(pady=10)
    button_1 = Button(gui_cv, text='Cartoonize', command=cartoonize, bd=4, bg='dodger blue2',
                      font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
    button_1.pack()
    gui_cv.mainloop()

h()
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Remove `gui_cv.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)`.Then it will show you.

Comment: Any alternative for what you have suggested @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: Use `Toplevel` and `Label` to replace `cv2.imshow()`.  Note that you need to convert the opencv image to PIL image and make the `Toplevel` a transient window of the root window.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 Now it's workingfine  with some changes you told me to do in my code.